# Trim decimal off a varchar value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a legacy SQL Server stored procedure that stopped working some time ago. While looking at it today, there is an inner join where one table is storing the value as an `int` and the other is storing it as a `varchar` in a (`##.#`) format.  Not sure why or how that happened but SQL Server is none too happy about it.

I need a simple programmatic bit of string manipulation to pull out everything to the left of the decimal point so I can cast or convert it to an int to fix the join.

I started with the following, however substring requires a fixed length and the data could be 1-3 digits to the left of the decimal. Having trouble with the dynamic aspect of it. For clarity sake, I don't care what's to the right of the decimal.

```
cast(substring(H.Variable, 1, 1) as int)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you store it as a decimal instead of a varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 CAST(TRY_CAST H.Variable AS Float) AS Int)
```

That should get you the integer value of the varchar string--if it cannot be converted, it will come back as NULL.

It's going in the  *other* direction than your question, but is likely to be more accurate and higher performance.

Note that you need SQL Server 2012 or later to use the TRY_CAST conversion...

Answer (score 3):

First, find the index of the decimal by using `CHARINDEX()`. Then, you can pass that index to the `LEFT()` function:

```
LEFT(H.Variable, CHARINDEX('.', H.Variable) - 1)
```

Comment: close, you need a - 1 after the charindex if there is a decimal

Answer (score 1):

If you can have no decimals with decimals, you need to account for that.

```
declare @table table (c1 varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('123')
,('5465465.465465')

select 
    case when CHARINDEX('.', c1) = 0 then c1 else LEFT(c1, CHARINDEX('.', c1) - 1) end
from @table
```

Other wise, only using `LEFT()` and `CHARINDEX()` will result in:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Another way is

`substring(c1,0,case when  charindex('.',c1) = 0 then 9999 else charindex('.',c1) end)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:
  `CONVERT(INT, H)`

It could be more tolerant...